# Error 404 when i try to get /registration page in node.js Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

So i made a registration and i use postman to send GET request with JSON. But even i just open /auth/registration without sendint GET, i GET 404))
App.js - block of code that sends 404 page

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});
```

auth_router.js - routes in my web app

```
const Router = require('express')
const router = new Router()
const controller = require('../authController')


router.post('/registration', controller.registration)
router.post('/login', controller.login)
router.get('/users', controller.getUsers)

module.exports = router
```

authController.js - class with functions, here is the logic of auth

```
const User = require('./models/User')
const Roles = require('./models/Roles')
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');


class authController {
    async registration(req, res) {
        try {
            const { fullname, username, email, password } = req.body
            const candidate = await User.findOne({ username })
            if (candidate) {
                return res.status(400).json({ message: "User with that username has already created!"})
            }
            const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
            const hashedPass = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
            const userRole = await Role.findOne({value: "user"})
            const user = new User({ fullname, username, email, password: hashedPass, profilePic, roles })
            user.save()
            return res.json({ message: "User created!"})



        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
            res.status(400).json({messgae: 'Registration error'})
        }
    }

    async login(req, res) {
        try {

        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
            res.status(400).json({ messgae: 'Login error' })
        }
    }

    async getUsers(req, res) {
        try {
            /*const userRole = new Roles
            const adminRole = new Roles({ value: 'admin' })
            await userRole.save()
            await adminRole.save()*/
            res.json('server works')
        } catch (e) {

        }
    }
}

module.exports = new authController()
```

[Here is the output of this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nry6W.png)

Sorry if questions is stupid, but i dont understand.
And one more question: How can I view errors if the application started normally? Let's say if you just run the .js code with a calculator, it will display an error in the terminal. How can I get them in the terminal as well? It now simply outputs them to the debugger log file.

I expect that i can send GET request with JSON data of user like:

```
{
    "fullname": "John",
    "username": "JohnS",
    "email": "25641@iitu.edu.kz",
    "password": "qwerty1"
}
```

Rest of the app.js (index.js) file:

```
'use strict';
const authRouter = require('./routes/auth_router')
var debug = require('debug');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
// var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

var mongoose = require('mongoose')

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', authRouter);
app.use('/auth', authRouter);
app.use(express.json());

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), async function () {
    await mongoose.connect(<here is my link>)
    debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
```

Comment: Can you provide the rest of the index file where the code for 404 fallback is present. Make sure you add the routes before adding the middleware for 404 fallback.

Comment: Can you also show what routes index file looks like.

Comment: Only: auth_router, index and users( users and index automatically created by visual studio project ). And there is no routes for errors

Comment: Can you try commenting out the line `app.use('/', routes);` and see if that fixes.

Comment: Now on the main page there is such an error as in registration.

Comment: Your registration sends a `GET` request? But you only defined a handler for `router.post('/registration')`?

Comment: @derpirscher is right. I now feel stupid to have missed that.

Comment: I send GET request with Postman. Registration only make .save() for Mongodb

Comment: Sorry i dont understand what should i write ?

Comment: @JohnStanley You only have route definition for POST request for `/registration` and that's why GET request is returning 404. If you want GET request to work as well you must add a definition like `router.get('/registration', controller.registration)` as well.

Comment: @DanPhilip `GET` requests typically don't have a `req.body` which OP tries to access during registration. `POST` is fine. You just have to tell postman to send a POST request instead of a GET

Comment: Thank you very much for you 2. Now i just getting message "registration error" according to my code ))))

Comment: @derpirscher I know, I was just trying to explain to the OP why the error was coming up.

Comment: Sorry, what is OP ?

Comment: @JohnStanley "Original Poster", ie the person who started this question. In this case: you ...